# Null Reference Exception for ClaimsType in IdentityCore, Getting claims as null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

Hi guys I am trying out Identity Core,

I need to get the details of the user who has logged in.

I am trying the following:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
   if (result.Succeeded)
     {
      string userRole=_signInManager.Context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
    }
```

I am getting a Null reference exception when getting the user roles

However I tried the same in a different controller then the Login Page of Identity Core and it is working.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't work as you expected because calling `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` only generates and sets authentication cookie for user and doesn't log in the user right now, thus there is no logged user in this request and that's why `_signInManager.Context.User` returns `null`. User is considered to be logged in only on next request where request contains that authentication cookie. So in general code for log in looks like this

```
_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return Redirect(...);
}
```

But if you want to get user information right after login you can do it like following

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
    IList<Claim> userClaims = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
    string userRole = userClaims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Value;
    //...
}
```

Or if you want to get only roles you may use this code

```
var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
IList<string> roles = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
string userRole = roles.First();
```

Comment: So the user isn't saved to the db immediately after sign in therefor the claims is null; Is there a way where I can get the user details immediately after sign in ? I am trying to define different redirect pages to users based on their roles after the sign in . Thank you:)